# Placing more text underneath the x-axis in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am thinking of ways to have more text underneath the existing x-axis values in gnuplot. For instance, how can I position additional text in brackets as shown in the below figure?

[image]

For now I have simply used Inkscape to modify the image file itself and entered the text manually. Any suggestions on other tools, if not gnuplot?

Comment: The solution by @theozh is probably the most flexible. For this particular example, it would be sufficient to use `set xtics format "% h\n(a)"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be the following. You may want to adjust the bottom margin and the offset of the xlabel.

**Code:**

```
### some more extra text at tics
reset session

set sample 11
set bmargin 4.5
set xlabel "x-label" offset 0,-1

plot [0:10] '+' u 0:1:xtic(sprintf("%g\n(a)",$1)) w lp pt 7
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Edit:**

You also can add different text for each label. Depending on your exact needs it might look for example like this:

**Code:**

```
### some more extra text at tics
reset session

set sample 13
set bmargin 4.5
set xlabel "x-label" offset 0,-1

TicData = "a b c A B C α β γ ant bat cat dog"
TicText(n) = sprintf("%g\n(%s)",int(n),word(TicData,int(n)))

plot [0:12] '+' u 0:1:xtic(TicText($0+1)) w lp pt 7 enhanced
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: How would the syntax have to be modified if there are unique symbols/text underneath each of the first row of x-labels?

Comment: how are the symbols/text related to the numbers? Is there a systematic rule, e.g. 1,2,3,4,5, ... --> a,b,c,d,e, ...  or do you have the symbols/text in a list or a file? i.e. which number gets which symbol/text?

Comment: Let's assume the symbols are known a priori. Let's go with a,b,c,d,e .. , as you mentioned.

Comment: it pretty much depends on what you need. I edited the answer and added an example.